# How to change the colour of MD icon using Tailwind and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, material-ui, material-design, tailwind-css

Hello I was wondering if it is possible to change the colour of a MD Icon using Tailwind.

I know I can change the style but I would just like to apply the tailwind class, it working using the background but its the undesired result.

```
<v-icon v-if="link.links" class="text-yellow-400">
    mdi-menu-down
</v-icon>
```

Kind Regards